# AES (RijndaelManaged) Decrypt Extra Characters?

Tags: vb.net, encryption, .net-2.0, aes

So, I'm using the `RijndaelManaged` class (.NET 2.0) to do AES-128 CBC encryption on small strings (around a dozen characters or less) in a config file. I've got everything working properly except that when I decrypt the data, the padding bytes are not removed. I understand I can choose to not do any padding but that is VERY insecure and that the padding bytes need to be added because that's how AES works (in discreet block sizes). Right now I'm using `PaddingMode.ISO10126` to let the `CryptoStream` automatically append crypto random bytes.

What is the industry-standard way of handling this? What's the right way of getting rid of these "extra bytes" on decryption?

Comment: Padding is added *and removed* automatically by the cipher as long as you correctly specify the padding mode, and tell the cipher instance that the block being decrypted is the final block, for example via `CryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way of getting rid of padding is of course to use PKCS#7 padding instead, and let the cipher instance get rid of the padding, as GregS suggested.

The best way of performing encryption nowadays is to use CTR mode encryption instead, or preferably a cipher that contains authentication/integrity protection such as GCM. Note that with small strings you need to take care not to reveal information through the size of the cipher text though (the result of performing CTR mode encryption on "yes" will result in three bytes, "no" will result in 2 bytes).

Comment: With CTR mode (and GCM as well) nonce discipline is essential. Reusing a nonce is *really* bad with those modes. But when used correctly, these are great modes IMO. Unfortunately .net has no out-of-the-box implementation for them.

Comment: @CodeInChaos Reusing or using a non-random IV is pretty bad in CBC mode too. MicroSoft is really slow regarding the implementation of new encryption standards, they are performing pretty badly for such a large company in that regard.

Comment: Yeah, I actually figured it out myself and the solution was just what you suggested. First, I needed to set the padding mode as you said. Then, when I'm decrypting, the decryption method returns an integer with then length of the decrypted value. I needed to only read up to that length, or else I'm reading garbage. I also found out that ISO10126 encryption is no longer recommended because it can introduce vulnerabilites. It doesn't matter if the padding text is predictable, because a good algorithm like AES is resistant to known plaintext attacks.

Comment: @owlstead why is reusing an IV bad? Currently I'm using the same IV to encrypt all of the values...

Comment: The same reason why using ECB is bad; if the plain text at the start is identical you will leak information. E.g. encrypt the word "Yes" two times. Both ciphertexts will be identical. And that's just eavesdropping.